# How to start For-Loop from beginn if the If-Condition is True

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I would like to know how do I start a `for`-loop from 0 if the `if` condition is True

```
for i in range (3):
   if a=1:
      #leave if-condition and start from beginning in for-loop with i=0
```

Break doesn't help here, because with break I only can leave the if Condition, but I also want to start the for loop from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead of the for loop.

```
i = 0
while i < 3:
    if a == 1:
        i = 0
    i += 1
```

This keeps walking through the loop if a equals 1

Answer (score -1):

I think you may write like this

```
if 1 == a:
    for i in range(3):
        pass
```